# Call a custom getter method from within initialize

Tags: ruby, object, initialization

I am trying to create a class that does a couple of things:
1) Implements a custom getter for an attribute
2) Calls the custom getter from within the initialize method

Here's what it looks like:

```
class Book

  # RSolr lib for interacting with Solr
  require 'rsolr' 

  # Instance variables 
  @isbn
  @title

  # Solr playlist instance URL
  @solr_domain
  @solr

  def initialize(isbn)
    @solr_domain = "http://solr.com:9003/solr"
    @solr = RSolr.connect :url => @solr_domain
    @isbn = isbn
    @title = self.title(isbn)
  end

  # Get Solr URL
  def solr_domain
    return @solr_domain
  end

# Set Solr URL and reset Solr connection object
  def solr_domain(newurl)
    @solr_domain = newurl
    @solr = RSolr.connect :url => @solr_domain
  end

  # Custom getter for title
  def title=(isbn)
    result = solr.get 'select', :params => {:q => 'isbn:(' + isbn + ')'}
    return result["response"]["docs"][0]["title"]
      end
end
```

The key lines are

```
@title = self.title(isbn)
```

where we attempt to call the getter for title, so that title gets set when the object is initialized.

What we want is a publicly accessible getter for title, as well as a way to populate @title during initialization of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For being able to preset the title, you could do something like this:

```
def initialize(isbn, user_title = nil)
  ...
  @title = user_title || self.title(isbn)
end
```

There's an optional argument the user can supply. If he/she does, `@title` will get set to that value, otherwise we'll look up the title ourselves with the ISBN. I hope I understood you correctly...

Edit: BTW, are you sure you want class level instance variables?

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the idea. That seems like it should work, but when I add the @title=self.title(isbn) to the initialize method, I get a "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" when attempting to instantiate a new Book object. (I also added a attr_accessor :title to the class)

Comment: Forget what I said about `attr_accessor`, I didn't properly read your example.

Comment: OK. The error had to do with how I was calling self.title. It should be self.title = isbn, instead of @title = self.title(isbn). And, I changed the title method to set @title inside of it, rather than explicitly setting it in initialize. I'm gonna give you this one, because you got me pointed in the right direction. Thanks for the extra link on the difference between class and instance variables - very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I feel that you are confusing instance variables of a class and instance variables of an instance. If you directly write `@...` in the class body, that will be the former, if you write `@...` within an instance method definition, it will be the latter. It seems you just want the latter. The following is probably what you want. Here, I set `solr_domain` and `title` as getters, so within some external class `A`, for some instance of `Book` `b`, you can do `b.solr_domain` or `b.title` to get them. Within `Book`, you do not need to access variables through getters. Directly accessing them by their names `@...` is less confusing and hence will likely decrease bugs.

```
class Book
  require 'rsolr' 
  attr_reader :solr_domain, :title
  def initialize(isbn)
    set_solr_domain("http://solr.com:9003/solr")
    @isbn = isbn
    @title = set_title
  end
  def set_solr_domain(newurl)
    @solr_domain = newurl
    @solr = RSolr.connect(:url => @solr_domain)
  end
  def set_title
    @solr.get('select', :params => {:q => "isbn:(#@isbn)"})["response"]["docs"][0]["title"]
  end
end
```